# For intraclass correlation coefficients (ICC), interpret both "single" and "average" measured ICC values for reproducibility test?

Tags: correlation, reliability, intraclass-correlation

Say there's a new machine for use in testing a biochemical marker's concentration in the blood, and we would like to know the reproducibility of this test.

We draw blood samples from 10 volunteers, and repeatedly measure the biomarker's concentration on each patient's blood sample five times.
(10 samples, each sample is measured for 5 times to have 5 values)

We have used ICC for test-retest reliability (2-way mixed-effects or one-way random-effects model) on SPSS: single measures ICC is about 0.6, and average measures ICC is about 0.97.

How would we interpret the result?

- Single measure ICC means a fair to good reproducibility if the test is performed at one of several occasions respectively.
- Average measures ICC means excellent reproducibility if you repeated the test for several times and calculate the mean value.

Can we say that based on these numbers?